# How to modify the "View all posts in category" title attribute

Tags: categories

I'm tyring to change the "View all posts in category" tooltip you see when you hover over a category link in wordpress. Until now I've always done it in the Wordpress core file named category-template.php  - however I'm searching for a method to do it in the functions.php so I don't have to change it after every Wordpress update.

I could only find this code to remove the "View all posts in category" title attribute alltogether, but I have no idea how to modify it:

```
add_filter( 'the_category', 'remove_category_title' );
function remove_category_title( $category ) {
return preg_replace( '/\s* title=\s*".*?"/i', '', $category );
}
```

I just want to change the text "View all posts in" and "View all posts filed under"

Comment: There are multiple instances of this string in WordPress core. Which function exactly are you asking about?

Comment: ideally every instance of "View all posts in" and "View posts filed under" in the core file category-template.php. In line 59 for example `$chain .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $parent->term_id ) ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $parent->name ) ) . '">'.$name.'</a>' . $separator;`

Answer (score 1):

Found something that works fine:

```
add_filter( 'the_category', 'remove_category_link_prefix' );
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'remove_category_link_prefix' );

function remove_category_link_prefix($output) {
    $replace = array( 
            'View all posts in',
            'View all posts filed under' 
    );

    return str_replace( $replace, 'Text you want to show up', $output);
}
```

found here: http://kaspars.net/blog/wordpress/remove-view-all-posts-filed-under-category-widget

Comment: He wants to edit, not to remove.